# How to retrieve data from AWS S3 to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssis

Wondering if i can get some help please. Our python developer has scheduled a process to web scrape some files on daily basis. Data will sit in AWS S3. Now i am trying to Import this data in to our SQL server database. What would be the best way to do this. Can we query the data from AWS S3 using SQL script ? Or do i need to download the files from S3 in CSV format and then process these using an SSIS package ? I would prefer to query AWS S3 only if it's possible.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read csv file directly from AWS s3 by using pentaho data integration. by using pentaho you can create job which will push data into sql server.
In pentaho DI go to

1. s3 csv input like below picture 
   [image]
2. then you can select your desired fields
3. then chosse table output object and create a connction with your sql server and map the imput fields with table column 
   [image]

Comment: Many thanks mate @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin. Apologies, i have never used pentaho before. Is this a Free tool ? specially if i would have to schedule it to import data from AWS on hourly basis.

Comment: @user3482527 yes it has community version which is open source and  so it is free tool . no problem in schedule you can do it

Comment: Many thanks. I will give it a try and will let you know. Much appreciated

Comment: There you go buddy. I trust your word so i have upvoted it :)